# Add custom URL segment to wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to allow my page to receive query variable but to rewrite it to nice permalink. So I wanted this

```
example.com/wordpress-page/random
```

So I don't want `random` to be a subpage or something like that, since it's coming from outside service. In order to do this, I've added this code to my `functions.php`

```
function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'my_var';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');

function do_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('wordpress-page/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=wordpress-page&my_var=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'do_rewrite');
```

When I go to `example.com/wordpress-page` I get my page, but when I go to `example.com/wordpress-page/random` I get 404 page.

I have flushed rewrite rules by saving permalinks in `wp-admin` panel.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to call the [flush_rewrite_rules()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) function. That was done in addition to the `query_vars` action hook and `add_rewrite_rule()` function you already demonstrated above.

In my case I chose to put it in my theme's functions.php using the [switch_theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme) action hook and deactivated/reactivated my theme. But you can probably put it elsewhere as long as it get's called *once* at some point (so probably not 'init')

```
add_action('switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options');

function mytheme_setup_options () {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```