# wordpress custom url with dummy content

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to add custom url with dummy content like belwo :

www.mysite/myparam/paramvalue

i want to show paramvalue on page load just

how can i do this .

i tried using :

```
add_action('parse_request', 'my_custom_url_handler');

function my_custom_url_handler() {
    if(**mycondition**){
      echo "<h1>TEST</h1>";
      exit();
   }
}
```

how i check my condition please guide

Comment: Does this describe your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051592/add-custom-url-segment-to-wordpress-page

Answer (score 0):

By default wordpress pages doesnot allow to create multitiered links. But you can use this plugin to create a customized link for any page or post, [Enhanced Custom Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-custom-permalinks/).

You can then create a page template or use plugins like [Allow PHP in Posts and Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/) to show the parts of url with the $_REQUEST super global.